# Drools: Rule firing twice for the same case

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine

This rule fires twice although there is only one matching case. I use Drools 6.5.0. Final. Looking at the log, it takes $card2 as $card1 and vice versa in the second round.

```
rule "Rule1"
salience 1
when
  $card1 : (used == false)
  $card2 : (used == false, number = $card1.number)
  exists Hand(name == name1)
  exists Hand(name == name2 || name == name3)
  not Hand(name == name4)

then
    $card1.setUsed(true); $card2.setUsed(true);
    insert(new Hand(name1, $card1, $card2));

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your rule looks malformed to me. The 2 first patterns are missing their types and there are variables (i.e. `name1`) that don't come from anywhere.

Second, remember that the LHS of the rules in Drools works kind of like an SQL statement. If you don't specify any relationship between your patterns, the cartesian product of them will be used.

Hope it helps

Comment: Additionally, RHS is missing `update()` for those facts which have been modified by calling the setters; or using `modify{}` block to perform the "used" field update

Comment: I added an attribute to each pattern which is numerically comparable, and it worked. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

No-Loop attribute for rule makes sure the same rule is not re-triggered when updates/ modify of same object that is used in the when condition takes place in the then statement.

The way to define no-loop is as below:

```
rule "Rule1"
no-loop true
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this but the rule still fired twice.